# about.me there was an error saving Backstory

Tags: user-profile

I have tried multiple times to edit the Backstory in about.me (a profile webpage) but it doesn't seem to work. The following message keeps popping up everytime i tried to edit my Backstory.

```
There was an error saving Backstory. Please try again later.
```

It seemed like a bug because my friend is also experiencing this. Anyone experiencing similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this bug has been resolved.